# Automatic refresh of Config Clients not working in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to migrate a simple example code with `Spring Cloud Config Server` and `RabbitMQ` as `Spring Cloud Bus` (based on `Spring Boot 1.5.22.RELEASE` and `Spring Cloud Brixton.SR7`) to  `Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE` and `Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3`. The example consists of a Config Server, a Config Client, `GitLab` as SCM and `RabbitMQ`(3.8 - Erlang 22.1.5). The code is compiling, starting up, the push webhook is triggered and can also be seen in the server's and client's log.

The problem is that the property updated in Git is not updated in the client. On the base of the `Spring Boot 1.5.22.RELEASE` and `Spring Cloud Brixton.SR7` it works reliable.
But if I do `curl -X POST http://localhost:8889/actuator/bus-refresh` manually, the property will be updated.

What can be the problem or which property have I forgotten to configure?

Here is my configuration/code:

**GitLab (started as Docker container)** 
Push WebHook: http://user:password@localhost:8889/monitor

**RabbitMQ (started as Docker container)**
no particular configuration

**`pom.xml` Root module of Config server and client:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>spring-config-server</module>
        <module>spring-config-client</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-config-mgmt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**`pom.xml` of Config Server:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-config-mgmt</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-config-server</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**`pom.xml` of Config Client:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-config-mgmt</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-config-client</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**`application.yml` of Config Server:**

```yaml
server:
  port: 8889

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@localhost:root/springcloudconfig.git
          clone-on-start: true

  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: DEBUG
```

**`application.yml` of Config Client:**

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: TRACE
```

**`bootstrap.properties` of Config Client:**

```
spring.application.name=config-client
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8889
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
management.security.enabled=false
```

**Config Server:**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Config Client:**

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@RefreshScope
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    @Value("${myProperty}")
    private String myProperty;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =1000)
    public void printProperty() {
        System.out.println("Value of property \"myProperty\": " + myProperty);
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the property `spring.cloud.bus.id` in `bootstrap.properties` fixed the problem:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/issues/124#issuecomment-423960553

Not really pretty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should set your config server name (example: `spring.application.name= configServer`)
and in config server set (example: `spring.cloud.bus.id = configServer:9000`) of course port should be your config server's port.